# Positive square rationals equidistant to 1

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Can there be two square rational numbers that are equidistant to $1$ i.e. there is a rational number $a \in [0,1]$ such that both $1-a$ and $1+a$ are square rationals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that two numbers that sum to 2 are equidistant to 1. Now take your favorite Pythagorean triple

$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2$$

and see that

$$\frac{(x - y)^2}{z^2} + \frac{(x + y)^2}{z^2} = 2$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint  :  $$1+49 = 2 \times 25$$

Comment: So $a=1/25$ and you assumed that it has numerator $1$ to check if this would work? Thanks though. I wonder if this is related to a more difficult diophantine equation.

Comment: Note:  also $ 1+1681=2\times841$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner there are many many more including $169+8281 = 529+7921 = 1225+7225 = 2209+6241 = 2 \times 4225$

Comment: @quantum - not quite: but $a=\frac{24}{25}$ works